# Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.3.40 and higher Error when upgrading android studio gradle from 4.2.2 to 7.0.0

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle

I have recently upgraded my Gradle version from 4.2.2. to 7.0.0. Android Studio was running the applications fine and well until i upgraded and got the below error

```
The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.3.40 and higher.
The following dependencies do not satisfy the required version:
root project 'MyNewApp' -> androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.3.0-alpha03 -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.20
```

Below is my project level grale

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0'
        //classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2'

        def nav_version = "2.3.0-alpha03"
        classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$nav_version"

        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I have tried adding ext.kotlin_version = "1.5.0" below buildscript but its the same same error what might be the issue

Comment: Please use the stable version [2.3.5](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation#version_235_3) as it has the [Use Kotlin-plugin 1.4.31 in safe-args](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/3a949c2a53232f2253802f435d043677db8cecba) commit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I changed my navigation version to below version and it has worked

```
def nav_version = "2.3.5"
classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$nav_version"
```